# How to remove fields from default values ​when saving a document in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I currently have a very large document, meaning many fields associated with it. I can't put them in separate collections, because this information needs to be together because of a grid.

However, this document has fields that I do not filter or order. And because of that I would like to remove them when saving the document using Spring Data MongoDB.

My question is if there is a way to ignore default value fields like boolean false, empty array, empty string when persisting an entity in the MongoDB database ?

Comment: You can try grouping these fields to be ignored together as a sub-document and this sub-document can map to a POJO reference which can be `null` when you don''t want to persist.

Comment: Use Wrapper classes instead of primitives. Wrapper class fields are not persisted if you don't set the value of it.